# Async Function in Getter w/ Return in Callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, ecmascript-5

I want to define a read-only object property that asynchronously fetches a value and then returns it using the new EcmaScript 5 getters.

However, the property always returns `undefined` even though `magicValue` in the example code below is definitively never undefined. Also, when I just `return 'xxx';` the printed value is still `undefined`. It only works when I `return` outside the callback function.

It seems like `return` is being executed immediately regardless of whether the callback of `myAsyncFunction` is called. 
I am not sure whether this a bug in in V8 or if I am abusing JavaScript's getters.
Can I get this to work? I thought, since I can use getters and setters now, I will use getters/setters to read and write properties and regular functions to do certain tasks.

```
var User = function (id) {
    this.id = id;
};

Object.defineProperty(User.prototype, 'magic', {
    get : function () {
        myAsyncFunction(function (magicValue) {
            return magicValue;
        });
    }
});

var u = new User(5);
console.log(u.magic);
```

Prints `undefined`.

Comment: You cannot return a result from an asynchronous function to a synchronous operation - it's an illogical construct. Moreover, your `myAsyncFunction` is never called - it's merely declared. What is the nature of your asynchronous operation?

Comment: The above code is just an example. The real purpose is that a _User_ has a property called "account". When the account property is accessed and the user does not already have an account, one will be created first and then it will be returned.

Comment: Over AJAX? But a getter is a synchronous operation. You cannot return something from the getter that is asynchronous - you'll need a different pattern.

Comment: Not over Ajax but through the file system. I see, I thought the getter will just need couple microsecs longer until it returns.

Comment: Nah - the getter is synchronous, and so will return (or not) immediately.

Comment: Do you think that if I synchronize (by using synchronous file system functions) the account creation function, It will be ok? It might still take the same amount of time until it returns.

Comment: Yes, if you make the operation synchronous that's an option, but you're blocking your script then. If at all possible I personally would try to find another pattern.

Comment: Ok, I think you are right. And what you say makes sense. I guess I'll just use a regular function instead. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asynchronous operations, these days, are typically handled with [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). When you invoke your getter, it returns a promise, which you can attach a callback with using the 'then()' method.

```
Object.defineProperty(User.prototype, "magic", {
  get: function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(JSON.stringify({
          magic: 'value'
        }));
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
});
```

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/tw6gaudz/2/

Comment: Is there a way to avoid Promises and use `async` & `await`?

Comment: @adelriosantiago: Async/Await uses promises underneath.  You can use an async function and await the getter.  

Here's a modified version using async/await: https://jsfiddle.net/z6hdbfwu/

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @utkanos for your help.

JavaScript won't acynchronously return a getter function's value because getters are synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a "setter":

```
var User = function (id) {
    this.id = id;
};

Object.defineProperty(User.prototype, 'magic', {
    set : function (value) {
        setTimeout(value.bind(0, "hello"), 1000);
        return true;
    }
});

var a = new User(5);

a.magic = function(msg){
    alert(msg);
};
```