# How to get asynchronous data from an object's `get()` without returning a Promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, getter-setter, defineproperty

In NodeJS, I have an object like,

`var scope = { word: "init" };`

Using [Object.defineProperty as described in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) I re-write the `get()` function to be like this,

```
Object.defineProperty(scope, 'word', {
  get: function() {
    return Math.random();
  }
});
```

Which correctly returns a new random each time I `scope.word` in the console. However the function must also get data from a function with a callback. So it works pretty much like a `setTimeout`,

```
Object.defineProperty(scope, 'word', {
  get: function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return Math.random();
    }, 1000)
  }
});
```

Now everytime I do `scope.word` I get,

> undefined

Because the `get()` function is synchronous. This can be of course solved by returning a Promise,

```
Object.defineProperty(scope, 'word', {
  get: function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(Math.random());
      }, 1000)
    });
  }
});
```

But then I would need to do `scope.word.then(...)` but the whole idea behind what we are building is that the developer only has to `scope.word` like if it was a plain easy-to-use variable. *Like an Angular's $scope or a VUE.js 'data'*.

**How can I make the `get()` function return an actual value, not a Promise? Is it possible to workaround using `async` / `await`? How?**

Comment: Just out of curiosity why do you need it to make an asynchronous function ?. Do you read that value from database or a http call ?

Comment: Using `async`/`await` won't _really_ help you. It will remove the `.then` but then you'd need to get your property like so every time: `await scope.word`. This may seem easier, but you also have to keep in mind that in order to use `await` it must be used within an `async` function. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/v7ohbsfx/

Comment: async/await is just a syntactic sugar. It will be something like `async function yourFunction() {
  var word = await scope.word;
}`

Comment: this question also addresses the same requirement .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843619/async-function-in-getter-w-return-in-callback

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Promises and async/await in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52641327/promises-and-async-await-in-nodejs) and [Using async await on custom promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46514570) and [Changing my callbacks, promise to async await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53607365)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Async Function in Getter w/ Return in Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843619/async-function-in-getter-w-return-in-callback)

Comment: No. You cannot get away with a returned promise without calling a CB or `await`.

Answer (score -1):

One of the solutions is to pass the callback function like this.

```js
    const scope = {}
    Object.defineProperty(scope, 'word', {
      value: (cb)=>{
         setTimeout(() => {
              cb(Math.random())
          }, 1000)
      }
    });

    scope.word(res=>console.log(res))
```